Kill processes longer than 1 hour matching a pattern
I am having an issue in a PHP application, where some processes seem to run for days - still trying to work out how/why but, whilst this happens, the resources on the server get zapped and loads goes way up. I then manually go in and kill the processes and everything is fine until it happens again
Therefore, as a stop gap, I want to run a cron to kill all php processes older than say 1 hour
When I get a list of processes it shows me below (I have removed all the ones which are not relevant)
  2049    7204994 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
  42146   42087   php-fpm: pool www -DFOREGROUND
  47118   49511   php-fpm: pool www
  47119   49511   php-fpm: pool www
  47162   47222   php-fpm: pool www -- uid 0 -- gid 0 -- logger=files
  47280   39490   php-fpm: pool www
  51993   12066   php-fpm: pool www
  51994   12066   php-fpm: pool www
  53634    8575   php-fpm: pool www
  53749    2590   php-fpm: pool www
  53775     766   php-fpm: pool www
  53780     447   php-fpm: pool www
  53781     358   php-fpm: pool www
  53784     111   php-fpm: pool www
  53797      26   php-fpm: pool www
  53799       0   ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd

I want to be able to kill any process older than 3600 seconds BUT not including the master process or those with additional arguments
If I try
ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd | awk '$2 > 3600 && $3 == "php-fpm: pool www"'

then nothing is returned at all.
If I try
ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd | awk -v pat="php-fpm" '$2 > 3600 && $3 ~ pat'

this returns me all of the above which I do not want as I do not want to kill the master process but if I try
ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd | awk -v pat="php-fpm: pool" '$2 > 3600 && $3 ~ pat'

OR
ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd | awk -v pat="pool" '$2 > 3600 && $3 ~ pat'

then I get nothing returned at all
How can I get this to return only those where the pattern contains exactly "php-fpm: pool www" and nothing else?

One suspect here is that your server is compromised. The server should be reinstalled and contents restored from a known clean backup.


still trying to work out how/why

Because this is exactly the job of the fast process manager.
The output you've shown us here is a set of mostly idle php worker processes. Your webserver submits requests to the master process (42146) which then checks if it has an idle process available to assign the request to. If not, and the defined limits will not be exceeded, it starts up a new process for the purpose.
Maintaining a pool of idle servers avoids latency waiting for a new process to start.
Actually FPM can start additional servers in advance of it running out of idle servers.
This is controlled by max_children, start_servers, max_spawn_rate min_spare_servers, max_spare_servers and process_idle_timeout
Killing processes is not the way to fix your problem

the resources on the server get zapped

Then 1) the limits in your FPM config are set too high 2) your workload exceeds the capacity of your hardware (more hardware is one solution, fixing your code is the other).

Regarding

awk '$2 > 3600 && $3 == "php-fpm: pool www"'

awk works on space-separated fields by default so none of the fields, including the 3rd field in your script, $3, can contain spaces. Here are the values of $3 for every line of your input so you can see that it never contains a space and so trying to match any regexp that contains a space can never work:
$ ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd | awk '{print $3}'
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
php-fpm:
ps

There's various ways to get the result you want, including testing the whole line instead of $3, e.g. using any awk:
$ ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd |
    awk '$2 > 3600 && /^ *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+ +php-fpm: pool www$/'
  47118   49511   php-fpm: pool www
  47119   49511   php-fpm: pool www
  47280   39490   php-fpm: pool www
  51993   12066   php-fpm: pool www
  51994   12066   php-fpm: pool www
  53634    8575   php-fpm: pool www

That assumes the white space in your ps output is blanks (the ps on my machine doesn't support -o so I can't test it), if not just change each blank followed by a * or + in the regexp to [ \t] or [[:space:]] or similar to match any possible white space.
